# Проблема с парсингом интерен-магазина. Python

Tags: python, парсер, интернет-магазин

Мне нужно спарсить некоторый магазин, а именно, название, ссылка на изображение и размеры товара. Проблема появилась с размерами, не могу их найти, ищу по css классу. Я подумал, что они приходят в другом запросе, но найти такой запрос не смог. Сможете помочь, или подсказать, что для этого нужно сделать или выучить? Использую aiocfscrape и BeatifulSoup
Вот товар для примера:
https://homegrownskateshop.com/products/Nike-SB-Zoom-Blazer-Mid-p533771990

Comment: "они приходят в другом запросе"

Answer (score 0):

В этом классе class="product-details__product-options details-product-options" есть класс class="product-details-module details-product-option details-product-option--size details-product-option--Size"

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Знаю, но я его не вижу когда получаю разметку с get запроса